# what does this xpath means "//Form/*[. = 'on']"

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, xmlnode, selectnodes

I am newbie in xml related things 
I am not able to understand  :

```
SelectNodes(@"//Form/*[. = 'on']");
```

Note : [SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is a function of [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).(related to [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=VS.80%29.aspx))

Please tell me what this code snippet means ?

Comment: @Cold Hawaiian code line is XmlNodeList selectedFields = formXmlDoc.SelectNodes(@"//Form/*[. = 'on']"); //Please not that formXmlDoc is of type XmlDocument.Xml is validated prior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` means the current element node, whatever it is. The predicate is checking the element's text node to see if it's the string `'on'`.

So that XPath query selects any nodes that are children of the `Form` node and have a value of `on`.

Comment: Some additional documentation for future reference, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256122.aspx) and [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

Comment: @BoltCock,Cold Hawaiian : If my input is "<Form><txtInput /><Selected>1</Selected></Form>" then what can be SelectNodes(@"//Form/*[. = 'on']").Count ? 0 or 1 ? And tell me in what case(what input) should be supplied(in reference with given input) to obtain SelectNodes(@"//Form/*[. = 'on']").Count NON-Zero or 1

Comment: @Pratik: It will be 0 because none of the elements have the word `on` in their values. If you want to select elements that have `<Selected>1</Selected>` inside, use `//Form/*[Selected='1']`

Comment: @BoltClock : Thanks. But what should be my input to obtain 1 without changing SelectNodes(@"//Form/*[. = 'on']");

Comment: @Pratik: What item in your form is selected? Does the `<txtInput />`  have any relation?

Comment: @BoltClock : No that is different component but its a part of it. Well <txtInput>on</txtInput> can this return 1 ?

Comment: @Pratik: Yes, that can return 1. Or you can change `<Selected>1</Selected>` to `<Selected>on</Selected>` instead

Comment: For your answer :  The predicate is checking the element's text node to see if it's the string 'on'.
Does that imply  <txtInput>on</txtInput>  to return 1 ?

Comment: Thanks. So in general this xpath will try to find 'on' in the child nodes of the current node(current node being .[dot]).

Comment: More readable than "." would be to use the text function, i.e. "//Form/*[text()='on']". Legend: "//" => "anywhere in the subtree", "*" => element of any name, "[<predicate>]" => "where predicate". Here, the expression is "any child of 'Form', anywhere in the tree, where text()='on'".